# Compare Two Files and Print Lines That Don't Match

Tags: linux, python-2.7, awk

I'm trying to compare two files (file1 and file2) and print the full lines from file1 that **don't** match the list from file2 - ideally in a new .txt file, however when I run awk it's not printing anything.

```
file1 example                    file2 example
12345 /users/test/Desktop        543252 
54321 /users/test/Downloads      12345  
0000  /users/test/Desktop        11111
                                 0000

expected output
54321 /users/test/Downloads
```

The command I've tried is

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next};a[$1] ==0' file1.txt file2.txt
```

ideally I'd like to be able to build this into a python program I'm writing (don't know if that's possible) if not I'd be happy for it to run through the linux terminal.

Any thoughts or pointers would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the expected output with `grep`:

```
grep -vf file2 file1
```

Comment: Thank you! completely overlooked grep and got fixated on awk!

Answer (score 4):

You have to correct your [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) like below

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ a[$1]; next } !($1 in a)' file2 file1
```